# SQL table view JOIN returning minimum value

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have two tables

```
      Combination
id | front_part | back_part
1  |     2      |     3
2  |     2      |     4

        Parts
id |     name       | inventory
2  |   black front  |     20
3  |   silver back  |     4
4  |   gold back    |     10
```

Here combination table has two columns related to parts table. I want to create a view which returns the minimum inventory of each combination which is minimum inventory of both parts.

Desired Table

```
combination_id |   inventory
            1  |   4
            2  |   10
```

What i get

```
combination_id |   inventory
            1  |   20
            1  |   4
            2  |   20
            2  |   10
```

Query I used:

```
CREATE view combination_inventory_view as
SELECT combination.id as combination_id,
    parts.inventory as inventory
FROM combination
LEFT JOIN parts 
    ON parts.id = combination.front_part 
    OR parts.id = combination.back_part
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always have two parts, I would use `least()`:

```
CREATE view combination_inventory_view as
    SELECT c.id as combination_id,
           LEAST(pf.inventory, pb.inventory) as inventory
    FROM combination c JOIN
         parts pf
         ON pf.id = c.front_part JOIN
         parts pb
         ON pb.id = c.back_part;
```

This should have much better performance than a query with `OR` in the `ON` clause.

If some parts might be missing, then you need a `LEFT JOIN` and need to handle this in the `LEAST()` (so it does not return `NULL`):

```
CREATE view combination_inventory_view as
    SELECT c.id as combination_id,
           COALESCE(LEAST(pf.inventory, pb.inventory), pf.inventory, pb.inventory) as inventory
    FROM combination c LEFT JOIN
         parts pf
         ON pf.id = c.front_part LEFT JOIN
         parts pb
         ON pb.id = c.back_part;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT combination_id,
 CASE WHEN p1.inventory<=p2.inventory
  THEN p1.inventory
  ELSE COALESCE(p2.inventory,p1.inventory) END AS inventory
FROM combination, parts p1, parts p2
WHERE combination.front_part = p1.id
AND combination.back_part = p2.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `min()` aggregate function and `group by`

```
CREATE view combination_inventory_view as
SELECT combination.id as combination_id,
    min(parts.inventory) as inventory
FROM combination
LEFT JOIN parts 
    ON parts.id = combination.front_part 
    OR parts.id = combination.back_part
group by combination.id
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the maximum value of a numeric column use the `MAX()` function.

`SELECT MAX(<numeric column>) FROM <table>; 
 SELECT MAX(<numeric column>) FROM <table> GROUP BY <other column>;`

To get the minimum value of a numeric column use the `MIN()` function.